# Is there a way to write a getter factory in Typescript using key name and value type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Background: trying to write some type-friendly FP in Typescript. Specifically I'm trying to write a getter factory function for returning a type-safe getter reading a value by a key from any type having that key with that value type.
It works if I define the types immediately:

```js
export const fnGetter = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(key: K) => (obj: T) => obj?.[key];
export const getTitleString = fnGetter<{title?: string}, 'title'>('title');
// console.log(getTitleString({title: 123})); // compile error, good
console.log(getTitleString({title: 'Hello'})); // => 'Hello'
```

But it is very verbose and I'd like to have the following:

```js
export const getTitleString = fnKeyGetter<string>('title');
// console.log(getTitleString({title: 123})); // compile error, good
console.log(getTitleString({title: 'Hello'})); // => 'Hello'
```

How should the `fnKeyGetter` function look for that to work? Is it possible to build a generic type from a key and a value type?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me and infer the types correctly:

```
function getPropertyFactorry<O>(key: keyof O) {
    return function(o: O) {
        return o[key];
    }
}
```

although I dont think this is the solution you re looking for.

Comment: I need a solution where you say "this is a getter pattern for any object having this key referencing this value type". In your solution the object type is already defined from the start.